# kibana 7: using drill downs in tables

Tags: drilldown, kibana-7

Kibana 7

I have a table visualisation with with a total column and two Unique counts.  I now want to be able to drill down into the cells to see a further level of detail for each of those cells.

```
Signature                                          Total    SrcIPs  DstIPs  
ET POLICY Vulnerable Java Version 11.0.x Detected   1,507        9       9
```

The table is in a dashboard and I have created dashboards for the targets of the drill down.  I added a drill down to the dashboard containing the table but I can't figure out how to attach this to a table cell and how the the filters get passed.

I.e. I want to click on the cell for the number of src IPs and have it display another table with a break down for that IP.

Click on the total cell take one to a dashboard that shows the individual alerts.

My searching finds docs saying it is possible but no explanations of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that with tables you can only do this with url drill downs and since they are not available on the basic license I am stuck.

Kibana will happily let you attach a dashboard drilldown to the table even though it won't work.